# Module not found: Can't resolve '../images/bg-header-desktop.svg' when importing image into React project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image

I am building a React project and I am having difficulties in importing a background image.  I am getting the error above.  The image is in an images folder which is in a public folder.  This is my structure of the app.
[image: Structure of folders]

The image is bg-header-desktop.svg.  This is how I want it to look like.
The code I have for the component is the following:

```
import React from "react";

import "./heading.styles.css";

const Heading = () => (
 <header>
 <div className="top-background">
 </div>
 </header>
 );

 export default Heading;
```

My css looks like this this:

```
.top-background {
height: 155px;
background-image: url(../images/bg-header-desktop.svg);
background-color: #5da4a4;
margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

This is how I would like it look.
[image: Top Bar image.]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you find the image when importing it in the React Component? Like ```import headerImage from "../../../public/images/bg-header-desktop.svg";```? Then I could think of a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this

```
.top-background {
  height: 155px;
  background-image: url("/images/bg-header-desktop.svg");
  background-color: #5da4a4;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```