# react giving error on tailwind class "bg-[url('/images/bg-header-mobile.svg')]"

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

This is the error

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css) 6:36-91
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'images/bg-header-mobile.svg' in '/Users/shivamchandra/Projects/frontEndMentor/static-job-listings-master/src'
```

The file structure is like this post

[Module not found: Can't resolve '../images/bg-header-desktop.svg' when importing image into React project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62020829/module-not-found-cant-resolve-images-bg-header-desktop-svg-when-importing)

what I am doing in my react app.js file

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App bg-[url('/images/bg-header-mobile.svg')] h-16 "></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: which tailwind version you are using

Comment: tailwindcss version 3.1.6

Comment: I can reproduce this on my machine, its a bug. Can you make issue in github  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution--
We have to specify the public folder in the path of image like this '/public/images/bg-header-mobile.svg'

Tailwind is not react.In react we can have an image folder inside public folder and and in src folder we can give path like '/images/bg-header-mobile.svg' But it is not allowed in tailwind we have to specify that images folder is inside public folder.

So it would look something like this

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App bg-[url('/public/images/bg-header-mobile.svg')] h-16 "></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As of today, using tailwindcss 3.1.8, the `/public/` prefix doesn't seem necessary anymore? In contrary, using `/public/` will lead to a 404 for this resource. `className="bg-[url('/images/bg-header-mobile.svg')]"` works for me (image located at `/public/images/`).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because dynamic attributes only work in JIT mode.

Add this to your tailwind.config.js

> mode: 'jit'

See: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Comment: I added the jit mode and purge as guided by the documentation but same error again

Comment: well tailwindcss has switched to jit mode as of v2.1 as mentioned here [link](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/just-in-time-the-next-generation-of-tailwind-css)

I don't think it is the problem